How to configure TCP keepalive for SpringBoot (Tomcat)?
I have a springboot (3.x) server using tomcat 9.x. The application.properties are configured as below, and I know that the options below are HTTP keepalive and not the TCP keepalive.
server.tomcat.keep-alive-timeout=10000
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=10000

From the Tomcat 9.x official doc, socket.soKeepAlive (SO_KEEPALIVE) default is false, so I have to configure it somewhere. Linux has default values for net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time, net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl, net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes. However although they are set, I didn't see any keepalive tcp sockets. I'm running the application server in kubernetes, so I configured the net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time very short using sysctl.
  securityContext:
    sysctls:
    - name: net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time
      value: "2"

I still don't see any keepalive tcp sockets.

How can I configure the TCP keepalive in my Springboot (Tomcat) server?

Why? Tomcat will time out idle connections anyway. TCP keepalive doesn’t buy you much in a Web server.
